# In chainer, how to early stop iteration using chainer.training.Trainer?

Tags: chainer

I am using chainer framework(Deep learning), suppose I have to stop iteration once two iteration's target function value's gap is little:  `f - old_f < eps`. but chainer.training.Trainer's stop_trigger is (args.epoch, 'epoch') tuple. how to trigger early stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented `EarlyStoppingTrigger` example according to @Seiya Tokui's answer, based on your situation.

```
from chainer import reporter
from chainer.training import util

class EarlyStoppingTrigger(object):

"""Early stopping trigger

It observes the value specified by `key`, and invoke a trigger only when 
observing value satisfies the `stop_condition`.
The trigger may be used to `stop_trigger` option of Trainer module for
early stopping the training.
Args:
    max_epoch (int or float): Max epoch for the training, even if the value 
        is not reached to the condition specified by `stop_condition`,
        finish the training if it reaches to `max_epoch` epoch.
    key (str): Key of value to be observe for `stop_condition`.
    stop_condition (callable): To check the previous value and current value
        to decide early stop timing. Default value is `None`, in that case
        internal `_stop_condition` method is used.
    eps (float): It is used by the internal `_stop_condition`.
    trigger: Trigger that decides the comparison interval between previous
        best value and current value. This must be a tuple in the form of
        ``<int>, 'epoch'`` or ``<int>, 'iteration'`` which is passed to
        :class:`~chainer.training.triggers.IntervalTrigger`.
"""

def __init__(self, max_epoch, key, stop_condition=None, eps=0.01,
             trigger=(1, 'epoch')):
    self.max_epoch = max_epoch
    self.eps = eps
    self._key = key
    self._current_value = None
    self._interval_trigger = util.get_trigger(trigger)
    self._init_summary()
    self.stop_condition = stop_condition or self._stop_condition

def __call__(self, trainer):
    """Decides whether the extension should be called on this iteration.
    Args:
        trainer (~chainer.training.Trainer): Trainer object that this
            trigger is associated with. The ``observation`` of this trainer
            is used to determine if the trigger should fire.
    Returns:
        bool: ``True`` if the corresponding extension should be invoked in
            this iteration.
    """

    epoch_detail = trainer.updater.epoch_detail
    if self.max_epoch <= epoch_detail:
        print('Reached to max_epoch.')
        return True

    observation = trainer.observation
    summary = self._summary
    key = self._key
    if key in observation:
        summary.add({key: observation[key]})

    if not self._interval_trigger(trainer):
        return False

    stats = summary.compute_mean()
    value = float(stats[key])  # copy to CPU
    self._init_summary()

    if self._current_value is None:
        self._current_value = value
        return False
    else:
        if self.stop_condition(self._current_value, value):
            # print('Previous value {}, Current value {}'
            #       .format(self._current_value, value))
            print('Invoke EarlyStoppingTrigger...')
            self._current_value = value
            return True
        else:
            self._current_value = value
            return False

def _init_summary(self):
    self._summary = reporter.DictSummary()

def _stop_condition(self, current_value, new_value):
    return current_value - new_value < self.eps
```

Usage: You can pass it to the `stop_trigger` option of `trainer`,

```
early_stop = EarlyStoppingTrigger(args.epoch, key='validation/main/loss', eps=0.01)
trainer = training.Trainer(updater, stop_trigger=early_stop, out=args.out)
```

See the [this gist](https://gist.github.com/corochann/7455ca705e325893bb25851f64df4ea3) for whole working example code.

[Note] I noticed that we also need to fix `ProgressBar` extension to pass `training_length` explicitly, if we use customized `stop_trigger`.

Comment: a very little mistake : EarlyStoppingTrigger(args.epoch, key='validation/main/loss', eps=0.01), but not "eps" pass to training.Trainer

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a callable object to the `stop_trigger` option. The callable object is called at each iteration by passing the `Trainer` object. It should return a boolean value. When the returned value is `True`, the training is stopped. In order to implement early stopping, you can write your own trigger function and pass it to the `stop_trigger` option of `Trainer`.

Other APIs that accept a trigger object also accepts a callable; see [the document of `get_trigger`](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/core/generated/chainer.training.get_trigger.html#chainer.training.get_trigger) for details.

Note: a tuple value for `stop_trigger` is a short hand notation of using `chainer.training.triggers.IntervalTrigger` as the callable.