# How to implement early stopping as an extension

Tags: chainer

As this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45891924/in-chainer-how-to-early-stop-iteration-using-chainer-training-trainer), we can stop iteration loop by setting function (f:trainer -> bool) as Trainer's stop_triger.
But in this way, I think we can't use other extension such as LogReport which use stop_trigger=((args.epoch, '10')).

So, my question is how to implement early stopping as the Extension and how to send a signal to stop trainer's iteration from Extension.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the example code on [gist](https://gist.github.com/corochann/7455ca705e325893bb25851f64df4ea3), 
and updated the answer on the original [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45891924/in-chainer-how-to-early-stop-iteration-using-chainer-training-trainer/46020563#46020563).

I noticed that `stop_trigger` originally uses tuple notation like `(args.epoch, '10')`, instead we need to change to pass a callable object (`EarlyStoppingTrigger` in above example).

Comment: Thank you for sharing the example